# Как перейти на следующую строку в TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

В макете разместил TextView. В нём размещён текст

```
android:text="Привет, как твои дела?"
```

Мне нужно так настроить TextView, чтобы слово "Привет," было в первой строке, а всё остальное во второй. Попробовал управляющие символы. Не помогло. Подскажите, как мне добиться желаемого результата?

Comment: Так пробовали: `android:text="Привет,\nкак твои дела?"`?

Comment: установи android:maxLines значение и должно \n работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ранее для подобной настройки использовался параметр `android:singleLine`, который отвечает за то будет ли доступен многострочный режим.

У нее было интересное поведение:

- по умолчанию она была равна `false` (т.е. многострочный режим был включен)
- НО если было задано значение, как у Вас, то по умолчанию данное свойство было равно `true` (т.е. многострочный режим отключался)

сейчас данный параметр помечен `@deprecated`, и вместо него рекоммендуют использовать параметр `android:maxLines`, в котором можно указать максимальное количество строк.

Укажите его, после чего добавьте управляющий символ `\n`

```
android:text="Привет,\n как твои дела?"
android:maxLines="10"
```

Comment: Даже не пойму в чём была проблема. Вставил управляющий символ \n (как и раньше делал).  maxLines пока не стал вставлять. Попробовал всё работает. Почему до этого не работало ума не приложу.

Comment: @gibsonff, ничего страшного. Зато что-то новое узнали и опыта набрались)